# Looping through json_decode with foreach loop error

Tags: php, json

I keep running into the error `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` and for the life of me I can't figure out why. Here is my relevant code:

```
$Ids = $_POST["param-0"];

$toReturn = array();

$decodedJson = json_decode($Ids,TRUE);

stripslashes($decodedJson);

foreach($decodedJson as $id)
{
    ... do stuff with $toReturn...
}
```

`$Ids` is a string from a previous file that is encoded with json_encode. I added the `stripslashes` because it was recommended in another question on Stack Overflow, but it didn't help. If I change the beginning of the foreach loop to be`foreach($toReturn as $id)` the error goes away. Thanks!

edit: in the previous file, $_POST["param-0"] is an integer array that I returned with json_encode. With the testing data I am working with right now, `["15","18"]` is what is being passed.

Comment: Can you post an example of your value for `$_POST["param-0"]`

Comment: Here's one more example of using `stripslashes()` to corrupt data.

Comment: I was running out of ideas, so I tried it on the hope that it might work, but I really didn't think it would.

Comment: One more thing. Your code should trigger several notifications from the PHP interpreter. You don't mention them so you're either ignoring them or you haven't configured PHP to display them. In either case, that's something to need to take care of before you go further. You cannot code without the aid of error messages.

Comment: That is the only error that my browser is displaying. I am not hosting this on a home server, so I will definitely look into the php configuration where it is being hosted, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up I was incorrectly encoding what I wanted decoded. All is well again, thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decode the json (which you already did)

```
$decodedJson = json_decode($Ids, True);
```

Then to grab each value from the json and, for example, echo it. Do this:

```
foreach ($decodedJson as $key => $jsons) { // This will search in the 2 jsons
 foreach($jsons as $key => $value) {
     echo $value; // This will show jsut the value f each key like "var1" will print 9
                   // And then goes print 16,16,8 ...
}
```

}

Comment: right now, with the small test case I have, it is just an array, like: ["15","18"] I changed the header of the foreach loop to be `foreach($decodedJson as $key => $id)` but that was a no go either (same error).

Answer (score 0):

From top to botton:

```
$Ids = $_POST["param-0"];
```

This will trigger a notice if input data does not have the exact format you expect. You should test whether the key exists, for instance with `isset()`.

```
$toReturn = array();
$decodedJson = json_decode($Ids,TRUE);
```

This will return `null` if input data is not valid JSON. You should verify it with e.g. `is_null()`.

```
stripslashes($decodedJson);
```

If input data was valid we'll first get a warning:

> Warning: stripslashes() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Then, if our PHP version is very old we'll have our array cast to a string with the word `Array` in it, and if our PHP version is recent we'll get `null`. Whatever, our data is gone.

If input data wasn't valid, we'll get an empty string.

```
foreach($decodedJson as $id)
{
    ... do stuff with $toReturn...
}
```

Neither `null` or strings (empty or not) are iterable. There's no nothing to do here. Our data is gone forever :_(